# Redirect several HTTP servers to HTTPS in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have an application that serves different pages(connects to a different DB) based on the subdomain name.

So, let's say I have subdomains `docs-for-app1.domain.com`, `docs-for-app2.domain.com` and `docs-for-app3.domain.com`. They use the same PHP code, so I'd like to configure only one server in nginx.

The configuration for this scenario can look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html/docs/;

    index index.php;

    server_name docs-for-app1.domain.com docs-for-app2.domain.com docs-for-app3.domain.com;

######################## REDIRECT ############################
##############################################################
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
##############################################################

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 10m;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except one thing. My firewall with proxy server is not able to redirect HTTP to HTTPS. I have to do it in the nginx server. As you can see I've tried to do it (marked part of the cfg) but it doesn't work as I expect. The problem is that `$server_name` always returns name `docs-for-app1.domain.com` no matter the real host name.

What is the right way to do this redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [`$server_name`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name)
>
> name of the server which accepted a request

To redirect to the 'requested' host use the [`$host`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host) variable;

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

> [`$host`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host)
>
> in this order of precedence: host name from the request line, or host name from the “Host” request header field, or the server name matching a request